# Decrypting AES 256 GCM - Audio Package finding

Tags: networking, encryption, aes, protocols

i am currently working on a project, in which i am trying to see the audio packages sent by my computer in a zoom call. I am doing this to manually check if there is a signal.

Alert: i am an extreme newbie to this whole field as i didnt get in touch with any of that. (currently studying bioinformatics)So sorry for any wrong terms and high simplification!!

The situation i think i figured out is the following:

In wireshark i found tcp and udp packages which seem to be the concerning ones for my case (audio via zoom).

Now I need to get the audio out of them. I dont want to steal anything, its just the audio I sent. I tried decoding it to RTP but it gives errors so i guess the data is encrypted.

Zoom seems to use AES-256 GCM encryption. But I have absolutely no clue if I can decrypt it manually (should be possible as my computer already encrypted it?!). If I could decrypt it I think the next step would be decoding it to RTP and then using the Wireshark analysis to get the waveforms.

Do you think it is anyhow possible to get the audio packages that are being sent - must be as my device is recording and encrypting it and i am the “owner”?

Do you have any tips?

i am really lost tbh

Thanks so much for any help

Thamori

as above described i t

Comment: Seems odd to me to try and grab the audio from the network packages. Usually one would use some software audio router and virtual audio devices to do this (i.e. set Zoom's audio source to a virtual microphone that can then be tapped by your software or mirrored as necessary). The only reason to not do this is if you don't trust Zoom to faithfully send your input (which is fair enough, I guess).